# url::redirect in kohana 3.1

Tags: php, kohana

I can't find function `url::redirect` in kohana 3.1
 What is the new name for this function ? (If it still exists !)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has been changed in Kohana 3 to...

```
$this->request->redirect($newUrl);
```

You can use that in a controller.

Otherwise, use (as [biakaveron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432669/biakaveron) kindly pointed out)...

```
Request::current()->redirect($newUrl);
```

Comment: There is no `Request::instance()` in Ko3.1, use `Request::current()` or `Request::initial()` instead (redirect can be done from any Request object).